# celery apply_async with redis backend not executing

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, celery, celery-task

My problem is im trying to run the parallel calls with `celery 4.4.0rc4` and `redis 3.3.8`. while im doing `apply_async` on a `group` of jobs im not getting any response back from the celery. It is waiting forever in the celery console but without redis backend tasks are executing. Problem with redis backend ?

```
new_list = []
for new_laptop in laptops_list:
    new_list.append(async_call.s(new_laptop))

result = group(new_list).apply_async()
result.join()
```

Im just returning a interger value from `async_call` function in celery file.

Comment: Do normal calls without grouping work?

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov without ```group``` atleast it will execute all the calls but was not returning to python process . With group it will execute first call and never returns back hangs in the celery console.